# JWT not being send on post request 401 error Angular and NodeJS

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I am making a MEAN stack with JWT and my backend with nodeJS work perfectly with postman, now when I try sending a post request then I get a 401 saying (from backend) that I am missing the token, which i am storing on the localstorage. Maybe my approximation of storing the token on the localstorage is wrong? Here is my code by files:

*AuthService.ts*

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  endpoint: String='http://localhost:8080/api';
  userToken: String;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.readToken();
   }

  logout(){

  }

  login(usuario: Usuario){
    const authData= {
      ...usuario
    }

    return this.http.post(`${this.endpoint}/auth/login`, authData)
      .pipe(map(resp =>{
        this.guardarToken(resp ['token'])
        return resp;
      })
      )
  }

  nuevoUser(usuario: Usuario){
    const authData= {
    ...usuario
  }

  return this.http.post(`${this.endpoint}/usuarios`, authData)
  .pipe(map( resp =>{
    this.guardarToken(resp['token'])
    return resp;
    })
    )
  }

  private guardarToken(xtoken:string){

    this.userToken = xtoken;
    localStorage.setItem('token',xtoken);
    //return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')|| '{}');

  }

  
  readToken(){
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') ){
      this.userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    }else{
      this.userToken = '';
    }

    return this.userToken
 
  }

}
```

*ApiService.ts*

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  apiToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
  //apiToken = this.auth.readToken();
  endpoint: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api';
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                              .set('Authorization', `token ${this.apiToken}`); 

  

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private auth:AuthService) { }

   // Add 
   AddCliente(cliente: Cliente): Observable<any> {
    let API_URL = `${this.endpoint}/clientes`;
    return this.http.post(API_URL, cliente, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        map((resp: any)=>{
          cliente._id = resp.nombre;
          return cliente;
        }),
        catchError(this.errorMgmt)
      )
  }
}
//more crud stuff
```

*interceptors*

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private auth: AuthService
      ) {}
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log("Interception In Progress");  
        //const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const token = this.auth.readToken(); 
        request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'token ' + token) });  
        request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });  
        return next.handle(request)  
        .pipe(  
           catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {  
                 
                if (error && error.status === 401) {  
                    console.log("ERROR 401 UNAUTHORIZED")  
                }  
                return throwError(()=>error);                      
           })  
        );  
  }
}
```

Edit: adding image of the headers

[image: headers description]

Comment: Does your HTTP include the correct headers? IT seems like just debugging this should provide the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes, i have try differents headers because of the same issue, still reciving the 401 with the message i made on Node that i am missing the token.

Comment: Do check your request in Dev-Tools->Network to see if the `Authorization` header includes your token. You can also try debugging your code to see if your token is being read correctly from `localStorage`

Comment: Yes is being send and still got the 401 error @Mike S.

Comment: Then your JWT is invalid then. so a 401 is the correct response. How do you generate the JWT? what auth method are you using, etc?

Comment: You seem to be reading the JWT out of localstorage `localStorage.getItem('token')` but no where do you seem to set this value.

Comment: JWT should be prefixed with `Bearer`. You should read the specs https://jwt.io/introduction

Comment: @Liam the JWT is genereted in Node with the user login info, and in the localstorage is the complete token i try with Bearer too with same response...401 with the msg from the backend that why i dont understand...

Comment: Try to log the token on Node.js? Is it reaching?

Comment: @Rupesh I try it with postman and it works just fine. Asking here is my last resource :'')

Comment: @Elneto  Just check if it reaching the server with angular. Try to log the headers. Only then we can tell if the issue is on angular or node?

Comment: @Rupesh ah no, is not reaching Node , on Network i got the msg from Node saying the token is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my code, front and back, i try adding the authorization in a separate line in my nodejs server as following:

```
res.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer");
```

then everything start to work as suppose, thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget to put in app.module this:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor ,
    multi: true,
  }..
```

Comment: I have it, double check it